# Test methods of Room DAO with Kotlin Coroutines and Flow

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I am trying to migrate from LiveData to Flow in my Room Dao. App is working fine, but I have problems with testing behavior. When I run the test it is starting and running indefinately.
I also tried to use **kotlinx.coroutines.test runBlockingTest**, but I had issue with "This job has not finished yet" like [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1222). Can someone point me in right direction how to test behavior of my CoresDao?

```
@Dao
interface CoresDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertCores(cores: List<Core>)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun replaceCoresData(cores: List<Core>) {
        deleteAllCores()
        insertCores(cores)
    }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cores_table")
    fun getAllCores(): Flow<List<Core>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM cores_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllCores()
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CoresDaoTest {

    private lateinit var database: SpaceDatabase
    private lateinit var coresDao: CoresDao

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    private val testCoresList = listOf(core2, core3, core1)

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, SpaceDatabase::class.java).build()
        coresDao = database.coresDao()
    }

    @After
    fun cleanup() {
        database.close()

        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetAllCores(): Unit = runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            runBlocking { coresDao.insertCores(testCoresList) }

            val coresList = mutableListOf<Core>()
            coresDao.getAllCores().collect { cores -> coresList.addAll(cores) }

            assertThat(coresList.size, equalTo(testCoresList.size))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To test Flow, the best APIs I found are `.take(n).toList()`. You can use `runBlockingTest` and you shouldn't need to use `withContext` to move the execution to another thread.

You can find an example of how it works here:
https://github.com/manuelvicnt/MathCoroutinesFlow/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/manuelvicnt/coroutinesflow/fibonacci/impl/NeverEndingFibonacciProducerTest.kt#L38

Comment: This may be a dumb question (I'm a Flow n00b), but is `take(n)` for how many items you want from the FLOW itself, or from a LIST you may have in the Flow? Like my DAO method returns a Flow<List<MyObject>>, so if I do `take(1)` would that just retrieve my List out of the Flow?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` already, using `runBlockingTest` won't do anything in your example..
You will have to `cancel` the `Flow` after collection or the `scope` in which you launched the `Flow`

edit: an example for such a rule can be found [here](https://github.com/floschu/control/blob/develop/control-test/src/main/kotlin/at/florianschuster/control/test/TestCoroutineScopeRule.kt)

Comment: The link is gone but the author has extracted out the rule into [this](https://github.com/floschu/flow-test-extensions) library to test `Flow`s.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that I wasn't properly handle Flow collection and cancelation and that was probably the cause of problem. Below is the code that works.
More complex example can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room/integration-tests/kotlintestapp/src/androidTest/java/androidx/room/integration/kotlintestapp/test/FlowQueryTest.kt).

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CoresDaoTest {

    private lateinit var database: SpaceDatabase
    private lateinit var coresDao: CoresDao

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    private val testCoresList = listOf(core2, core3, core1)

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        database = Room
            .inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, SpaceDatabase::class.java)
            .setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .build()
        coresDao = database.coresDao()
    }

    @After
    fun cleanup() {
        database.close()

        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @Test
    fun testInsertAndGetAllCores() = runBlocking {
        coresDao.insertCores(testCoresList)

        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            coresDao.getAllCores().collect { cores ->
                assertThat(cores.size, equalTo(testCoresList.size))
                latch.countDown()
            }
        }

        latch.await()
        job.cancel()
    }
```

Comment: While this works, the test will still run indefinitely if the code inside `collect` throws any error, like for example if the assert fails.

Comment: Thank You for pointing this out. Currently I am using method from accepted answer, which seems fine.

Comment: My test, just like yours, just keeps spinning. In the `collect { }` mine just asserts that the List isn't empty and then calls `countDown()`. Then after that the `await()` and `cancel()` calls. That method above is the same as what's in the more complex example, well one of the comlex example's functions anyway. One of them has a `produceIn()` call instead. No clue what the difference is or what I should use. I should just convert my app to just return `List` instead of this Flow crap.